# Oracle SQL : concatenation - missing expression

Tags: sql, oracle

I am using the `Employees` table to practice the following:

I would like to display a column with a statement saying

```
This is my New salary after 10% increase :- and salary + 10%
```

Below is the script I used but it didn't work

```
select 
    Salary,
    'This is my new Salary after 10% increase :- ' || Salary + 10%, 
From 
    Employees;
```

Comment: "...it didn't work" doesn't help much. In the future, please include whatever error messages you're receiving in the body of the question. Thanks.

Comment: ORA-00936: missing expression
00936. 00000 -  "missing expression"
*Cause:    
*Action:
Error at Line: 34 Column: 1

Comment: here is the exact error

Answer (score 0):

Huh, that's what you can only wish (I mean, invent your own syntax). Should have been e.g.

```
SQL> select sal,
  2    'This is my new salary after 10% increase: ' || sal * 1.1 as result
  3  from emp
  4  where empno = 7369;

       SAL RESULT
---------- -------------------------------------------------------------------
      1000 This is my new salary after 10% increase: 1100

SQL>
```

Comment: how did you come up with 1.1?

Comment: I am also confused about the following: So to apply your solution to my example,       Sal = Salary, emp = Employees , but what is :  empno = 7369 ?

Comment: 1.1 is 1 + 10% - so multiplying a value by 1.1 produces the result "value + 10 percent". If you need to review this you might consider working through [this Khan Academy lesson](https://www.khanacademy.org/test-prep/praxis-math/praxis-math-lessons/praxis-math-number-and-quantity/a/gtp--praxis-math--article--percentages--lesson)

Comment: do I have to have 'where' in my script ? I would like the increase to apply to all rows. Maybe i am mistaking but I dont see a reason to use 'Where'

Comment: @AnouarSeljouki No, a `where` cause is not required.

Answer (score 0):

Please try this:

```
select 
Salary,
'This is my new Salary after 10% increase :- ' || Salary * 1.1 NEW_SAL
From Employees;
```

---

Output:
2600    This is my new Salary after 10% increase :- 2860

Comment: it came back with an error " Missing expression" what is NEW_SAL?

Comment: NEW_SAL is an alias. You can put any name instead. Replace it wi: AS RESULT or any other column name.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should be able to use val + its 10%, so 110% of the val.
Furthermore you cannot use 110% (you would be forced to cast it etc.) so it is much better to use 1.1 of the val.

```
SELECT 
   sal AS Salary,
   'This is my new salary after 10% increase: ' || sal * 1.1 AS 'New Salary'
 FROM emp;
```

So for all employees you should see their current salary and 110% of the salary.